# Change the title of Selectpicker using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

- I Want to **change the title** of the Selectpicker using jquery **when button is clicked** but it does  not work for me
- Following is the code

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap-select.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script>
    $("#chapter").attr("title", "Select Chapters");
</script>
<div class="col-md-5">
  Select Chapter: 
 <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="chapter" multiple data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search" title="Select Class First" data-actions-box="true">   
 </select>
    <br />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `prop` instead of `attr`

Comment: i have tried prop but it not works.

Comment: do you want it to change on submit button click or on page load ?

Comment: I want it to change on submit button.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your Jquery code to

```
$('#chapter').prop('title', 'New title');
$('#chapter').selectpicker('refresh');
```

```js
function change(){
  
 // $('#chapter').prop('title', 'New title');
  // $('#chapter').selectpicker('refresh');
  
  $('.bootstrap-select .filter-option').text('New title'); 
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap-select.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- (Optional) Latest compiled and minified JavaScript translation files -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/i18n/defaults-*.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="col-md-5">
  Select Chapter: 
 <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="chapter" multiple data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search" title="Select Class First" data-actions-box="true">   
 </select>
    <br />
    <button onclick='change()' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Change</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Hudhaifa Yoosuf for your reply but it is not working

Comment: please check now, i have updated it change on button click.. i have tested and it works